# Sort of the table datatables jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, plugins, datatables

I use the DataTables plugin to display the data but I change the data of the table with PHP and AJAX:

```
$aColumns = array(
  'entity_id',
  'entity_immatriculation',
  'entity_designation',
  'categorieentity_label',
  'emplacemententity_label',
  'familleentity_label',
  'entity_date_destruction',
  'entity_prix',
  'id_entity_etat'
);

Model::factory('entity')->_ajax_entity($aColumns,$this->_controller);
```

Module :

```
foreach($rResult as $aRow)
{
  $row = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++)
  {
    if ($i == 6)
    {
      $row[] = $compteur;
    }   
  }     
}
```

The display is OK but the sort of the table is always by the old value `entity_date_destruction` Please help please.

Answer (score 0):

you can use syntax below to change default sorting.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var data = table
.column( 0 )
.data()
.sort();
```

It will sort w.r.t first (0) column.